# Python: Given a link, how to save locally if the link is an image and do not save if it is not an image?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am currently using

```
import urllib

urllib.urlretrieve("http://www.digimouth.com/news/media/2011/09/google-logo.jpg", "local-filename.jpg")
```

Is there a way to see if the link contains a pic or not, if not then no need to download, if so, then download.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by *if the link contains a pic or not*?

Comment: You have to analyze file extension.

Answer (score 1):

The extension does not mean a file is an actual image, if you want to check that the file is indeed an image you could use  [imagemagik identify](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php):

```
from subprocess import check_output, CalledProcessError
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import requests
from shutil import move

r = requests.get("http://www.digimouth.com/news/media/2011/09/google-logo.jpg").content
tmp = NamedTemporaryFile("wb", delete=False, dir=".")
tmp.write(r)


try:    
    out = check_output(["identify", "-format", "%m", tmp.name])
    print(out)
    move(tmp.name, "whatever.{}".format(out.lower()))
except CalledProcessError:
    tmp.delete = True
```

To see all the format supported run  `identify -list format`.